# L1 Regularized least square

Tags: python, least-squares

I am trying to solve the below lasso optimization function by L1 regularized least square method. I am using python for my project.

```
α'* = arg min (||y’–B’α’||_2^2 + λ||α’||_1)
```

Here `α'*` is a vector. Dimension of  `B’=(m+p)*p`, `y’=(m+p)*1`, `α‘=p*1`

I couldn't solve this equation. Please anyone explain the `eqn` and method to solve this eqn in `L1` regularized least square method.

Comment: Is question asking for programming implementation or are you looking for a mathematical explanation?

Comment: I am asking for implementation. I am writing a program for imputing missing values in given data set using Locality constrained spare representation method. As a part of this method, I need to find the coefficient vector by solving the above Eqn. But I couldn't get how to solve the above Eqn.

Comment: You can try using sympy : http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html
Though I am not sure of the complexity it can handle

Comment: There is no `Y'` in the equations?

Comment: Y' was meant y' (small y)

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem that can solved with [ODL](https://github.com/odlgroup/odl):

```
import odl
import numpy as np

m = 2
p = 100
lam = 0.00001

# Define B
B = odl.MatrixOperator(np.random.rand(p, m + p))
alpha_true = np.random.rand(m + p)
y = B(alpha_true)

# Define functionals
l2dist = odl.solvers.L2NormSquared(B.range) * (B - y)
l1 = lam * odl.solvers.L1Norm(B.domain)
func = l2dist + l1

# Initial point
alpha = B.domain.zero()

# Solve using steepest descent
odl.solvers.steepest_descent(func, alpha,
                             line_search=0.0003, maxiter=10000,
                             callback=lambda x: print(func(x)))
```

If you want a faster solution, you should look into proximal methods (also available in ODL). One such example is the FISTA method:

```
import odl
import numpy as np

m = 2
p = 100
lam = 0.00001

# Define B
B = odl.MatrixOperator(np.random.rand(p, m + p))
alpha_true = np.random.rand(m + p)
y = B(alpha_true)

# Define functionals
l2dist = odl.solvers.L2NormSquared(B.range) * (B - y)
l1 = lam * odl.solvers.L1Norm(B.domain)
func = l2dist + l1

# Use FISTA
alpha = B.domain.zero()
odl.solvers.accelerated_proximal_gradient(alpha, l1, l2dist,
                                          gamma=0.0001, niter=1000,
                                          callback=lambda x: print(func(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas... But I am facing dimension issue here... I have B and y matrixes.  My B dimension is (m+p)*p  ( not (m*p) )  and y is p*1 ...   For example, B is 102*100 and y is 100*1 ,    When run this code, i am facing the following error,                                                                                   "OpTypeError: `range` rn(144) of the right operator OperatorVectorSum(MatrixOperator() not equal to the domain rn(142) of the left operator L2NormSquared(rn(142))"

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, i updated the answer to follow your convention closely and it now works as expected

Comment: Thanks a lot Joans.... Here i have y matrix  that is numpy array. so when i use that y, i am having the following error " 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'gradient' " .  Can you please suggest a solution for this issue??? Can i convert this numpy array to desired data type i.e odl.space.npy_ntuples.NumpyNtuplesVector????

Comment: Sure, just do `y = operator.range.element(y)`

Comment: I am getting this error   " AttributeError: module 'operator' has no attribute 'range' ". Can you look into this pls?

Comment: Should have been `B.range.element`, sorry.

Comment: Hi Jonas,  now i am getting different error  " 
ValueError: expected input shape (144,), got (144, 1) ".     I have changed the y shape to (144,)  from (144,1), but still i am getting this error.

Comment: Then you need to ravel the data first, e.g. `B.range.element(np.ravel(y))`